# Create new operator in F# with explicit datatype

Tags: f#, new-operator

Is there a way I can explicitly the elements of a new operator I define?

I've checked the doc but couldn't find it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading#creating-new-operators

Let's say I have defined the following `xor` operator:

```
let (^@) a b =
    a <> b

let result = true ^@ false
```

It works correctly, but the following definition no...

```
let (@^) (a: bool, b:bool) : bool =
    a <> b
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `@^` the parameters are tupled. Your operator needs two parameters. If you specify

```
let (@^) (a: bool) (b: bool) : bool =
    a <> b
```

then

```
true @^ false // true
```

Comment: Thanks! still not used to the sintax.